# Pagination with help from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Community, I currently have some pagination on my page to help users page through logged tickets.  To help with this, I have two table cells with Next and Previous in each respectively.  Right now, when a user clicks either, it adds +1 or -1 to a JS counter that AJAX's a string.  Then, I have my pagination that either goes to the next or previous 15 items in my mysql database.  I wrote my JS so that if the counter is less than 1 it will go back to one.  That way they dont have to repeatedly click the next button to view tickets.  I'm trying to figure out a way to do that from the other end, where if the end of the result list is blank, or no more results are available, it will stay at the last counter.
PhP including initial table setup and string variable

```
include 'Search_Var.php';  //This file is used to build $sequel.
                           //$sequel is a string built by user selected search options
echo '<div style="display: none" id="Search_Var">'.$sequel.'</div>
<div class="container" style="clear: both;">
<fieldset>
<legend class="legend1"><h2> &nbsp Results &nbsp </h2></legend>
<div style="padding-top: 5px;">
<span id="page">';
include 'Search_Tickets.php';  // This file builds a table to show the first 15 results
                               // It also displays the total number of tickets found
                               // in the database matching the search query
echo '</span>';
if($openTicketsCount!=0) {include '********/***********/PreviousNext.inc.php';};
//If no tickets are available the Previous and Next boxes won't appear.
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
';
```

Javascript

```
var count = 1;
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var id = document.getElementById( "Search_Var" ).innerText;
    $('.page').on('click', function() {
        var page = $(this).html();
        if(page == "Next")
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if(page == "Previous")
        {
            count = count - 1;
        }
        if(count < 1)
        {
            count = 1;
        }
        $.get("/*******/********/Search_Pagination.inc.php?count_id=" + count + "&search_id=" + id, function(data) {
            $('#page').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Finally, the pagination

```
$start = 0;
$per_page = 15;
$page = $_GET['selection_id'];
$_SESSION['role_id'] = $_GET['role_id'];
$_SESSION['bus_id'] = $_GET['bus_id'];
$_SESSION['dept_id'] = $_GET['dept_id'];
if($page <= 1)
{
    $start = 0;
}
else
{
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
}
$get_openTickets = $search;
$openTicketsCount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($get_openTickets));
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($get_openTickets));
$num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
$get_openTickets .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
if($openTicketsCount !=true)
{
    echo '
    <td colspan = "9">No open tickets were found!</td>
    ';
}
else
{
    $result = mysql_query($get_openTickets);
    echo '
    <table class="openTickets" width="1150px" border="0px" padding="0px">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">PRIORITY</th>
      <th scope="col">CALLER /<br />DEPARTMENT</th>
      <th scope="col">COMPANY NAME /<br />SALES REP</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">CREATED<br />ON</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">LAST<br />UPDATED</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">SOURCE</th>
      <th scope="col">USER</th>
      <th scope="col">CATEGORY /<br />SUBCATEGORY</th>
    </tr>
';
    while(($openTicket = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
    {
        echo'
        <tr>
          <td><a href="?page=ViewTicket&ticket='.$openTicket['call_id'].'">'.$openTicket['call_id'].'</a></td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['priority_name'].'</td
          <td>'.$openTicket['caller_name'].'<br />'.$openTicket['caller_dept'].'</td>
          <td>'.$openTicket['cust_name'].'<br />'.$openTicket['cust_rep'].'</td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['created_on'].'</td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['updated_on'].'</td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['source_name'].'</td>
          <td>'.$openTicket['created_by'].'</td>
          <td>'.$openTicket['cat_name'].'<br />'.$openTicket['subcat_name'].'</td>
       </tr>';
   }
   echo '
   <tr>
     <th colspan="9" style="text-align:right;">Total Open Ticket(s): '.$openTicketsCount.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
   </tr>
   </table>';
}
```

Comment: please post a jsfiddle

Comment: just create a function that returns the amount of search results, or in the rendering part, just render a hidden input that stores the count of the search results, remember no paging when doing the count, you want the max total it can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look below

```
$start = 0;
$per_page = 15;
$page = $_GET['selection_id'];
$_SESSION['role_id'] = $_GET['role_id'];
$_SESSION['bus_id'] = $_GET['bus_id'];
$_SESSION['dept_id'] = $_GET['dept_id'];
if($page <= 1)
{
    $start = 0;
}
else
{
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
}
$get_openTickets = $search;
$openTicketsCount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($get_openTickets));
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($get_openTickets));
$num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
$get_openTickets .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";
if($openTicketsCount !=true)
{
    echo '
    <td colspan = "9">No open tickets were found!</td>
    ';
}
else
{
    $result = mysql_query($get_openTickets);
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$num_pages.'" id="pageCount"/>
    <table class="openTickets" width="1150px" border="0px" padding="0px">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">PRIORITY</th>
      <th scope="col">CALLER /<br />DEPARTMENT</th>
      <th scope="col">COMPANY NAME /<br />SALES REP</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">CREATED<br />ON</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">LAST<br />UPDATED</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width:75px;">SOURCE</th>
      <th scope="col">USER</th>
      <th scope="col">CATEGORY /<br />SUBCATEGORY</th>
    </tr>
';
    while(($openTicket = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
    {
        echo'
        <tr>
          <td><a href="?page=ViewTicket&ticket='.$openTicket['call_id'].'">'.$openTicket['call_id'].'</a></td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['priority_name'].'</td
          <td>'.$openTicket['caller_name'].'<br />'.$openTicket['caller_dept'].'</td>
          <td>'.$openTicket['cust_name'].'<br />'.$openTicket['cust_rep'].'</td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['created_on'].'</td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['updated_on'].'</td>
          <td style="width:75px;">'.$openTicket['source_name'].'</td>
          <td>'.$openTicket['created_by'].'</td>
          <td>'.$openTicket['cat_name'].'<br />'.$openTicket['subcat_name'].'</td>
       </tr>';
   }
   echo '
   <tr>
     <th colspan="9" style="text-align:right;">Total Open Ticket(s): '.$openTicketsCount.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
   </tr>
   </table>';
}
```

And then change this

```
var count = 1;
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var id = document.getElementById( "Search_Var" ).innerText;
    $('.page').on('click', function() {
        var page = $(this).html();
        if(page == "Next")
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if(page == "Previous")
        {
            count = count - 1;
        }
        if(count < 1)
        {
            count = 1;
        }
        if(count > parseInt( $("#pageCount").val()))
        {
            count = parseInt($("#pageCount").val());
        }
        $.get("/*******/********/Search_Pagination.inc.php?count_id=" + count + "&search_id=" + id, function(data) {
            $('#page').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Edit:

It might be that the page count is not an integer so just check that the page count returns a valid integer, also added parseInt, it might be the reason why it was not working

Comment: I tried your suggestion as seen above.  I like the idea in theory, but it wasn't working.  Would it be perhaps that pageCount is on the page that is being ajaxed to?

Comment: can you check if this element is rendered to the browser `<input type="hidden" value="'.$num_pages.'" id="pageCount"/>`

Comment: Yes, it is being rendered.  I am using IE 9 if that helps.  Thanks

Comment: @CBC_NS are you getting any javascript errors? IE 9 should have developer tools, try pressing F12, also try in Chrome's developer tools to see if there is any errors

Comment: after reviewing your initial response I realized it was me who made a typo.  Secondly, I tried using the same code in Firefox.  What was happening was it was throwing a mysql_num_rows error.  I'm not sure if that is strictly a Firefox issue or not.  However, once I attempted it again in IE 9 which is our main supported browser it worked a charm.

Comment: @CBC_NS then I am happy

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why "Add Comment" is not shown for me,

But I wanted to say dont use functions mysql_*

Try using something like PDO